# Cursor adapter _id move forward by 1

Tags: android, database, android-cursoradapter

I'm having some issues working with a CursorAdapter.

In `bindView()`, I retrieve data in this way:

```
final String id = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MySQLiteHelper.PROF_CONTACTS_KEY_ID));        
final String name = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MySQLiteHelper.PROF_CONTACTS_KEY_NAME));
```

Right after this code, I call

```
Log.e("Log",id+" <=> "+name);
```

But, because of some weird problem, I got as a result an ID moved forward by 1.

This is the situation in the DB (pulling it from the emulator, and opening it with SQLite Manager):

[image: Database situation]

And this is the output:

[image: Logcat]

With bigger numbers (>9), IDs start to mess even more up: number 10 becomes number 1, number 13 becomes number 5, etc.
I wouldn't have a lot of problems, in fact the only thing not matching is the id, all other info correspond, but I have a details activity to which I pass the ID in order to show to the user the detailed info.

This is the piece of code where I apply the adapter:

```
    mCursor = mDb.rawGet("SELECT * FROM "+MySQLiteHelper.PROF_CONTACTS_TB_NAME+" LEFT JOIN "+
            MySQLiteHelper.EXAMS_TB_NAME+" ON "+
            MySQLiteHelper.PROF_CONTACTS_TB_NAME+"."+MySQLiteHelper.PROF_CONTACTS_KEY_COD_ESAME+"="+
                MySQLiteHelper.EXAMS_TB_NAME+"."+MySQLiteHelper.EXAMS_KEY_COD 
            + " ORDER BY " + MySQLiteHelper.PROF_CONTACTS_TB_NAME+"."+MySQLiteHelper.PROF_CONTACTS_KEY_ID);

    if (mCursor.getCount() == 0) {
        // error stuff.
    } else {

        String[] columns = new String[] {};
        int[] to = new int[] {};

        mDataAdapter = new CursorAdapterProfContacts(getSherlockActivity(), R.layout.item_prof_contact, mCursor, columns, to, 0);
        mLvContacts.setAdapter(mDataAdapter);

    }
```

Comment: It shouldn't matter or change your problem because of how SQLite stores things, but you should use getLong when retrieving your _id since it is, in fact, a long.

Comment: Are you sure that you have _id correctly populated when you insert a value? You can extract the database if you use the emulator and open it with SQLiteManager plugin for Firefox. As well, instead of quering all with *, use the same projection column names as you use inside y our bindView(); something is not matching here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was due to a collision name: _id can be referred both to EXAMS and PROF. SQLlite chose EXAMS instead of PROF.

```
    mCursor = mDb.rawGet("SELECT *, "+
                    MySQLiteHelper.PROF_CONTACTS_TB_NAME+"."+MySQLiteHelper.PROF_CONTACTS_KEY_ID+" AS idProf "+
                    " FROM "+MySQLiteHelper.PROF_CONTACTS_TB_NAME+" LEFT JOIN "+
                    MySQLiteHelper.EXAMS_TB_NAME+" ON "+
                    MySQLiteHelper.PROF_CONTACTS_TB_NAME+"."+MySQLiteHelper.PROF_CONTACTS_KEY_COD_ESAME+"="+
                    MySQLiteHelper.EXAMS_TB_NAME+"."+MySQLiteHelper.EXAMS_KEY_COD +
                    " ORDER BY " + MySQLiteHelper.PROF_CONTACTS_TB_NAME+"."+MySQLiteHelper.PROF_CONTACTS_KEY_ID);
```

And finally

```
    final Long id = c.getLong(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("idProf"));
```

This made the trick.
Collision name errors should be thrown, as it is in SQL and MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

Move the cursor to the first row,after initial cursor like, 
mCursor.moveToFirst()

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you have _id correctly populated when you insert a value? You can extract the database if you use the emulator and open it with SQLiteManager plugin for Firefox. As well, instead of quering all with *, use the same projection column names as you use inside y our bindView(); something is not matching here

Comment: Please, take a look to the edited answer: it looks like the DB is perfectly populated.